# iOS OAuth 1.0 requestToken user authorization: how do I detect when a UIWebView is done with the authorizing?

Tags: ios, oauth, uiwebview

I'm working my way through the OAuth 1.0 flow on an iPhone app.

I have the requestToken. I segue to a UIWebView with the proper URL to perform user authorization of the requestToken, which performs successfully. However, the user has to tap "back" manually after this step is done to get back to the app. The user then taps a separate button to perform the getAccessToken. (this is obviously work in progress).

How do I automate the going back after performing the user authorization of the requestToken? On the UIWebView, when the user successfully logs in, then they get a page verifying permissions, and the user clicks "OK", I want the app to automatically go back and proceed with getting accessToken once that is complete.

I'm new at this, so may not be explaining this too well. FWIW, I'm working with smugmug APIs. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth implementation or just use the library as it supports working with custom OAuth services

Comment: Thanks. I've downloaded this and taken a look at it. I'm still new to iOS dev so I'm swimming in it a bit right now, hard to follow what they do. But that's a good reference, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by looking for a particular URL, then manually popping the navigationController stack when the right URL finished loading. My code looks something like:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSRange range = [webView.request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"http://thecallbackurl.com/"];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

I'm writing to smugmug.com APIs. On token authorization success, they redirect the browser to the callback URL, so that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iOS coder but once the request token has been authorized by the end user, the service provider should redirect to your callback. There must be a way for you to "listen" for this in the UIWebView. Either by picking up on the redirect HTTP response which would look something like this:

```
301 Moved Permanently
Location: URI?oauth_token=BLAHBLAH&oauth_verifier=BLAHBLAH
```

If you can intercept that redirect you can probably hinder the UIWebView from actually completing it and instead just scrape the Location header.

Or, you should at least be able to by pick up on when the redirect has completed and you are actually on your callback page. Then it would be a simple case of scraping the URL containing the token and verifier from the invisible addressbar. If all else fails you can have your callback actually print the token and secret on the page and scrape that.

Once you have the verifier you should be able to get your access token without involving the end user at all.